# Accuracy/train and Loss/train graph by tensorboard

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, tensorboard, gradient-descent, loss

i used tensorboard for my pytorch project and got this result for accuracy/train and loss/train but i dont understand what it means
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loss does not decrease and your accuracy does not increase during training. Not significantly.

First thing to try is adjusting the learning rate:
- One possibility is that the learning rate is too small, and therefore the weight updates are tiny and insignificant. Try increasing the learning rate by factor of x10 or even x100.
- On the other hand, your loss/accuracy do seem to oscillate, which may suggest update steps are too large. Try decreasing the learning rate by x10 and see if this oscillation subsides.